# JSP trigger onclick event programmatically

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a device, which uses JSP to create the webpage, to maintain itself. There are some onclick events, and I would like to get some information from this device via a stand alone application, which only connects via IP to this device, and get all the information.

So, is it somehow possible to get directly to the functions, which are normally triggered via onclick events, so that non-human programs can open these pages?

Thank you

Comment: select the element, call click. Think this is the 3rd time this type of question has been asked today. If the clicks are making calls why not just grab the call and use those to get the data.

Comment: If I use firefox to look at the event it tells: https://192.168.0.1/management/Main.jsp

function onclick(event) {
  openDivWindow(10, "Program");
  return false;
}
So it's not just a link to a site - it is a real function which opens a new Div Window

Comment: It would be in the network panel if it makes any api calls.

Comment: `document.getElementById("foo").click()`